# Size Element to String that is not the Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button (`<span>`) that has text in the format `Options (3)`. The number can change, and the worst case will be `Options (99)`.

Is there a way to have the minimum width of this span be sized according to my worst-case so the layout doesn't change when the number changes?

My current approach is

```css
span {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

span::after {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  content: attr(data-min-string-width);
}
```

```html
<span data-min-string-width="Options (99)" style="background: red">
  Options
</span>
<br>
<span data-min-string-width="Options (99)" style="background: lime">
  Options (1)
</span>
<br>
<span data-min-string-width="Options (99)" style="background: cyan">
  Options (99)
</span>
```

Does anybody have something nicer?

Comment: I must admit your approach is quite clever. Certainly not something I would have thought of!

Comment: Why not just set the width to the maximum width you'd ever get? Also, please don't link out to your code on 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include your code, right here in your question as a "code snippet" (as I've done for you).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the edit! I avoided hard-coding the width because if the site font doesn't load or I add internationalisation, the width will be wrong

Comment: If you use [`em`](https://www.w3.org/Style/LieBos3e/em.en.html) units (which is a size that is relative to the inherited font size), those two scenarios won't be issues.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing for a fact that `Options (99)` is your widest span you could change your `::after` styles to this:

```
span::after {
    color: transparent;
    content: 'Options (99)';
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will ensure "Options (99)" always makes up the width of your spans.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar way of @alexander-valencia answer...

You can see the `:after` with `content: 'Option (99)';` will be everytime and it will fit the width of the div container.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div:after {
  display: block;
  content: 'Options (99)';
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span data-min-string-width="Options (99)" style="background: blue">
  Options
</span>
<br>
<span data-min-string-width="Options (99)" style="background: lime">
  Options (1)
</span>
<br>
<span data-min-string-width="Options (99)" style="background: cyan">
  Options (99)
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Display: block definitely makes things nicer. Thanks!